# Music ends prematurely using yt_dlp for a discord bot in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, yt-dlp

I use the yt_dlp module to get songs to play for my discord bot, the following is the command I use

```py
@music.command(name="play", description="Plays the music you specified", aliases=["pl"])
async def play_music(ctx, *, query):
    if not str(ctx.guild.id) in queue.keys(): queue[str(ctx.guild.id)] = []
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(yt) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(query, download=False)
        video_entry = info.get('entries', [info])[0]
        url = video_entry['url']
        queue[str(ctx.guild.id)].append(url)
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            voice_client = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
        else:
            voice_client = ctx.voice_client
    for i in queue[str(ctx.guild.id)]:
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url), **{'options': '-vn', "before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5"})
        queue[str(ctx.guild.id)].remove(i)
```

I searched for several solutions and i was given `**{'options': '-vn', "before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5"})` as kwargs to pass but it gives me the error that "options" and "before options" are unexpected arguments

Answer (score 0):

```py
ffmpeg_options = {
   'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
   'options': '-vn'
}

voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url), **ffmpeg_options)
```